# How to use __VA_ARGS__ properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have define VLog like this:

```
#define VLog(s, ...)  NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])
```

I know `VLog(@"hello,%d%@", 1, @"a");` `__VA_ARGS__` is replaced with 1, @"a".

Whereas, `VLog(@"hello");` `__VA_ARGS__` is replaced with what?

and if I define VLog like this:

```
//delete ##
#define VLog(s, ...)  NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__])`
```

`VLog(@"123");` is pointed out error.

Comment: you can use it like printf function. such as VLog (@"test = %@, %@",@"123",@"456"); ##__VA_ARGS__ is array of arguments. (%@, %@) is replace with (s)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053275/what-is-in-c/12055446#12055446

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII , the link helps me understand ## nicely, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of zero variable arguments, `__VA_ARGS__` is replaced with nothing. `##` is special in that it removes preceding `,` in that case, so compiler won't complain "expression needed after comma". A macro defined without `##`, i.e. `[NSString stringWithFormat:(s), __VA_ARGS__]` will *require* additional arguments.